# Hiding the phone number when calling from iOS or Android App

Tags: android, ios, architecture

This might not be an appropriate question for StackOverFlow. If not please recommend me where I can post this question.

We are in the process of developing an application where the customer can call the vendor and the vendor can call the customer. But for privacy reasons we don't want to expose the phone numbers of the customers to the vendors and vice versa.

What are some recommended solutions for this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible as of now. You could hide the phone number by replacing each number as an asterisk (*) in your app.

However, when vendor or customer taps on the phone button to call, then phone number is passed to the device Operating System to call, then this number will show up in the calling list.

In addition to that, your app most likely will not be allowed by Apple reviewers, because user needs to see what phone number he is calling. He might be punished if he keeps calling this secret/scripted phone number which might be 911. That is another serious issue may rise.

My recommendation is to have chatting system, or implementing VoIP(voice over IP) like whatsup or viber style calling within the app. It requires exhausted implementation.

Comment: If that is the answer, please mark it. If not, please add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, the URL Scheme requires a number and it is show on the screen while calling.

as you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

Maybe, you may have to create something more complex like Skype.